# How to modify field values in Java class with annotations?

Tags: java, annotations

I was thinking about how to modify the field values ​​of the java class with annotations, but I didn't find any article about it. The my idea is make an annotation to masked or format values by pattern provided by user. Example:

```
public class MyClass{
   @Mask("XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX")
   private String cardNumber = "4871049999999910";
}
```

When i call cardNumber atribute the return value will have to be "4871 0499 9999 9910".
Someone can i help me? thanks for your attention

Comment: As the name implies annotations provide information, they don't change values. You'd need some code to actually process the annotation via reflection. Why don't you just apply the formatting in the getter?

Comment: You can validate your String by `@Pattern` annotation, actually changing value will be more troublesome

Comment: I dont apply the formatting in the getter because i'm using lombok to generate Getters and Setters in my class and i wish it was with annotation but as it is not possible, i will apply formatting otherwise

Comment: You can override specific Lombok generated code - significantly simpler than annotation (and probably an Aspect to intercept getters that refer to annotated properties)

Comment: thanks for tips, my solution was override the get method